# How to use variable in function after load PHP file in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to use variable "hotel" after load `step-02.php` file?

```
    $(function () {
    var hotel = [];
    $('#forPrice').on('click', function() {
        $('select').each(function() {
            if($(this).val() > 0 && $(this).val() < 10) {
                var room = {};
                room["room"] = $(this).attr('room');
                room["price"] = $(this).attr('price');
                room["val"] = $(this).val();
                room["html"] = $(this).parents(".selectRowRoom").html();

                hotel.push(room);
            }
        });
        console.log(hotel);
    });

    $('#forPrice').click(function () {
        $('#Step-01').hide();
        $('#Step-02').show();
        $('.hiddenAndShow').hide();
        $( "#Step-02" ).load( 'step_02.php' );
    });
})
```

I need

> room["html"] = $(this).parents(".selectRowRoom").html();

to show after loading step-02.php.

`step-02.php`:

```
<div class="thisRoom">
    // Insert room["html"] = $(this).parents(".selectRowRoom").html();
</div>
```

Comment: where are you loading php file?

Comment: @xzegga Hi, I got this question correct.

Comment: So are you trying to tell us `.thisRoom` is in step_02.php or what ?

Comment: @adeneo yes, insert in `.thisRoom` in `step-02.php`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0rh9qwm0/

Comment: @adeneo Tank you so much, just `JSON.stringify(hotel)` -> `hotel[0]['html']`

Comment: You're welcome *(I just added something so you could see the object, hence JSON.stringify)*

Comment: @adeneo please insert answer in stackoverflow , I would like to...

Comment: Sure, done !.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery `load()` is a shortcut for `$.ajax`, which is asynchronous, you have to wait for the result to be able to access it.

Luckily `load()` has a callback that fires when the content is inserted and ready for accessing

```
$(function() {
    var hotel = [];
    $('#forPrice').on('click', function() {
        $('select').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() > 0 && $(this).val() < 10) {
                var room = {};
                room["room"] = $(this).attr('room');
                room["price"] = $(this).attr('price');
                room["val"] = $(this).val();
                room["html"] = $(this).parents(".selectRowRoom").html();

                hotel.push(room);
            }
        });
        console.log(hotel);
    });

    $('#forPrice').click(function() {
        $('#Step-01').hide();
        $('#Step-02').show();
        $('.hiddenAndShow').hide();
        $("#Step-02").load('step_02.php', function() { // callback here
            $("#Step-02").find('.thisRoom').html(JSON.stringify(hotel));
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make `hotel` global and save key number of room in data attr. Like this :

```
$(function () {
    window.hotel = []; // new
    $('#forPrice').on('click', function() {
        $('select').each(function() {
            if($(this).val() > 0 && $(this).val() < 10) {
                var room = {};
                room["room"] = $(this).attr('room');
                room["price"] = $(this).attr('price');
                room["val"] = $(this).val();
                room["html"] = $(this).parents(".selectRowRoom").html();

                $(this).data("numRoom", hotel.length); // new
                hotel.push(room);
            }
        });
        console.log(hotel);
    });

    $('#forPrice').click(function () {
        $('#Step-01').hide();
        $('#Step-02').show();
        $('.hiddenAndShow').hide();
        $( "#Step-02" ).load( 'step_02' );
    });
})

//After :
hotel[$(this).data("numRoom")]["html"] = $(this).parents(".selectRowRoom").html();
```